# Registering Startup Class In Nancy Using AutoFac Bootstrapper

Tags: nancy

I've been reading through a lot of the [Jabbr](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR) code to learn Nancy and trying to implement many of the same patterns in my own application. One of the things I can't seem to get working is the concept of an on application start class. The Jabbr code base has an `App_Start` folder with a `Startup.cs` file ([here](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR/blob/master/JabbR/App_Start/Startup.cs)) in it with the following implementation.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...

        SetupNancy(kernel, app);

        ...
    }
 }

private static void SetupNancy(IKernel kernel, IAppBuilder app)
{
    var bootstrapper = new JabbRNinjectNancyBootstrapper(kernel);
    app.UseNancy(bootstrapper);
}
```

When I tried to do something similar to that in my project the `Startup.cs` file was just ignored.  I searched the Jabbr code base to see if it was used anywhere but I wasn't able to find anything and the only differences I could see is Jabbr uses [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) while I wanted to use [AutoFac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

Is there a way to register a startup class in nancy?

Take a look at my project over on [GitHub](https://github.com/cnwilkin/ChainLink), you'll be interested in the Spike branch and may have to unload the `ChainLink.Web` project to run I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the `Nancy.Bootstrappers.Autofac` nuget, inherit from the AutofacNancyBootstrapper type and override the appropriate method (depending on your lifetime scope requirements: application or request). For more info check the readme file https://github.com/nancyfx/nancy.bootstrappers.autofac

HTH

Comment: Yes I've seen that but don't I have to pass in a `ILifetimeScope` to my custom bootstrapper and use `GetApplicationContainer()` to register my own types? I can't seem to `builder.RegisterType<MongoDbRepository>().As<IChainLinkRepository>();` inside of the `protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(ILifetimeScope existingContainer) { }`.

Answer (score 14):

I had some trouble finding a way to configure the ILifetimeScope even after reading the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17329365/891573) by [TheCodeJunkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25319/thecodejunkie). Here's how you do the actual configuration:

In the bootstrapper class derived from the [AutofacNancyBootstrapper](https://github.com/nancyfx/nancy.bootstrappers.autofac#usage), to actually configure the request container, you update the ILifetimeScope's *component registry*.

```
protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(
    ILifetimeScope container, NancyContext context)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<MyDependency>();
    builder.Update(container.ComponentRegistry);
}
```

The application container can be updated similarly in the ConfigureApplicationContainer override.

Comment: Works. This should be added to the Github page of Nancy.Bootstrappers.Autofac!

Comment: For some reason it is added here: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Container-Support#autofac

Answer (score 0):

After following the advice from [TheCodeJunkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25319/thecodejunkie) you can use the `Update` method on the `ILifetimeScope` container parameter which gives you a `ContainerBuilder` through an `Action`:

```
protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(ILifetimeScope container, NancyContext context)
{
    container.Update(builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyType>();
    });
}
```